# How does the rank of $C_i$ change with $i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $k$ be a field. Let $A,B\in k^{m\times n}$ and $$C_i=\pmatrix{A&B&&&\\&A&B&&\\&&\ddots&\ddots&\\&&&A&B}\in k^{im\times(i+1)n}.$$ Then how does the rank of $C_i$ change with $i$? I conjucture that, for $i$ large enough, there exist non-negative integers $d,s$ such that the following equality holds: $$\mathrm{rank}(C_i)=id+s.$$
**Edit:** Ilya Bogdanov gave a positive answer to the above conjucture. If we let $$C_i=\pmatrix{A_1&A_2&\cdots&A_s&&\\&A_1&A_2&\cdots&A_s&&\\&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\&&&A_1&A_2&\cdots&A_s}\in k^{im\times(i+s-1)n},$$ where $A_1,\dots,A_s\in k^{m\times n}$. Is the conjucture still valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is true. Let us apply Gauss' elimination method with some changes.

First, apply it to the first $(A\; B)$, among others, you obtain several rows containing nonzero values only in the $B$-area, with ones at some positions; let the fragments of these rows in the $B$-area span some subspace $U_1$.

Now you may vanish the elements of the next $A$ in these positions and apply Gauss' method to the rest of the second $(A\; B)$. You again obtain some rows nonzero only at the (second) $B$-area, and they will span some subspace $U_2$ containing $U_1$.

Acting so, in each next $A$ you will vanish (non-strictly) more positions than in the precious one, so you get a chain of subspaces $U_1\subseteq U_2\subseteq \dots$. After it has been stabilized, everything will work in the same way, so the rank of obtaines matrix will gain a constant increment at each step.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how is the general case?

Comment: The general case is the same as the second step. At the first few (at most $m$) steps the rank may behave non-linearly, as the dimension of $U_i$ may increase chaotically, but then it is linear. If you wish some explanation --- please tell what is unclear...